Discover Background Color
When checking updates in Discover the more detailed information about an update is displayed as black text against a rich blue coloured background:

This is hard to read.  Would a kind person please tell me how I might change the background colour, maybe it is set in a config file hidden away somewhere in my HOME directory?
Thank you in anticipation ...

Which version of Kubuntu? Also, did you install any custom themes?

Out of the box Ubuntu Studio 22.04. I didn't install any custom themes. Your question begs another. If this is a non-standard look, is there anywhere that describes what Standard should look like?

Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04 ||
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7 ||
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0 ||
Qt Version: 5.15.3 ||
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-40-lowlatency (64-bit) ||
Graphics Platform: X11

Can you open system settings and tell us what is the theme being used?

Ubuntu Studio Light.  With Ubuntu Studio Dark the white text on the same blue background look fine.  Just does not work with black text on blue when using Ubuntu Studio Light theme.

Probably the theme was not well tested. Switch to the Breeze theme. It should have better compatibility

Ububtu Studio Light is based on Breeze.  Breeze has a paler blue, which is slightly more readable.  Still not great in my opinion.  Black text needs a very pale background colour or none at all.  When I raised this question I thought it would be easy to fiddle with.  A new LTS Ubuntu Studio is on the way so I won't make changes now.  US Dark is good for Discover but rubbish for LibreOffice Style Manager panel (black text on black background!).  Thank you for taking an interest.

This may help for libreoffice dark theme https://itsfoss.com/libreoffice-dark-mode/. Otherwise, you can set libreoffice to use a light theme by editing its desktop file
